# header Location и $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

Задаю перезагрузку страницы, перенаправляя на "себя-же":

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Значение `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` не передаётся. Происходит перенаправление в корень сайта.

```
$location = "Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo $location; //Location: /exapmle/content/
header($location); //перенаправление произойдёт опять же в корень.
```

При этом если вписать значение "руками":

```
header("Location: /exapmle/content/");
```

Перенаправление произойдёт корректно.

Ещё один пример:

```
$location = "Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]."goto/";
echo $location; //Location: /exapmle/content/goto/
header($location); //перенаправление произойдёт на /goto/.
```

Переменная `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` так же не выводит текущий адрес.

**Вопрос №1:** Почему переменные `$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]` и `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` не передают своего значения в `header("Location: ");` ?

**Вопрос №2:** Существуют-ли другие способы перезагрузки страницы из php скрипта? *(Перезагрузка производится для потери параметров, передаваемых с помощью `$_POST`, что бы страницу можно было свободно обновлять, не подтверждая отправку данных и не дублируя запросы `$_POST`)*

Comment: Если память мне не изменяет, то $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] содержит ссылку по которой получили текущую страницу. А javascript использовать можно, или только средствами PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поставить в начало скрипта поставить, скорее всего у вас ошибка, которую вы не видите:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

P.S. не используйте $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"], это [не стандартная](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)  переменная.

Comment: На ошибки всё проверял error_reporting(E_ALL); показывает на несуществующие переменные, что нормально. error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); - ничего не выводит. Код чистый.

Comment: Какой минимальный код, для воспроизведения ошибки ?

Answer (score -1):

Если перенаправляете на "себя же", тогда используйте `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`
Если же хотите завернуть как вы описали, тогда используйте, как вариант, такое

```
header( "Location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```